# Unable to get webpage using aiohttp ClientSession

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I would like to use asyncio to get the webpage.

However, when I executed the code below, no page is obtained.

The code is

```py
import aiofiles
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import asyncio

async def get_webpage(url, session):
    try:
        res = await session.request(method="GET", url=url)
        html = await res.text(encoding='GB18030')
        return 0, html
    except:
        return 1, []

async def main_get_webpage(urls):
    webpage = []
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=60)       
    async with ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
        tasks = [get_webpage(url, session) for url in urls]
        result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for status, data in result:
            print(status)
            if status == 0:
                webpage.append(data)
        return webpage

if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ['https://lcdsj.fang.com/house/3120178164/fangjia.htm', 'https://mingliugaoerfuzhuangyuan0551.fang.com/house/2128242324/fangjia.htm']
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    webpage =  loop.run_until_complete(main_get_webpage(urls))
```

I expect two zeros will be printed in the function `main_get_webpage(urls)`.

However, two ones are printed.

What's wrong with my code?

How to fix the problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's wrong with my code?

What's wrong is that you have a `try: ... except:` that masks the source of the problem. If you remove the `except` clause, you will find an error message that communicates the underlying issue:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gb18030' codec can't decode byte 0xb7 in position 47676: illegal multibyte sequence
```

The web page is not encoded as GB18030. The page declares itself as GB2312 (a pre-cursor to GB18030), but using that as the coding also fails.

> How to fix the problem?

Depending on what you want to do with the web page text, you have several options:

1. Find an encoding supported by Python that works with the page as given. This is the ideal option, but I wasn't able to find it with a short search. (Using [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1187379) to find out what chrome thinks the page uses didn't help either, because the response was `GBK`, which against produces an error on character 47676.)
2. Decode the page with a more relaxed error handler, such as `res.text(encoding='GB18030', errors='replace')`. That will give you a good approximation of the text, with the undecipherable bytes rendered as the [unicode replacement character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm). This is a good option if you need to search the page for a substring or analyze it as text, and don't care about a weird character somewhere in it.
3. Give up the idea of decoding the page as text, and just use `res.data()` to get the bytes. This option is best if you need to archive or cache the page, or index it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I cannot get the correct encoding and I need the content. So I take solution 2.

Comment: @Chan No problem. There's also `errors='ignore'`, which will completely remove the offending sequences.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way maybe just use `await res.text()` instead of `await res.text(encoding='GB18030')` because as https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html?highlight=encoding#aiohttp.ClientResponse.text said

> If encoding is None content encoding is autocalculated using
> Content-Type HTTP header and chardet tool if the header is not
> provided by server.

I will argue that if `aiohttp` didn't use the `charset` in `Content-Type` to decode the response text, its implementation is rather problematic. You really don't need to provide encoding parameter.

I check the 2 urls in your example, `Content-Type` are both `text/html; charset=utf-8` so you can't use GB18030 to decode them.